# Preventing user to upload too big of a file in perl

Tags: perl, buffer, buffer-overflow

Hi guys i have this line of code in a perl script where i allow users to upload a 5 second microphone recording to my server. The flash that does the recording automatically limits the microphone to 5 seconds and then POSTs the recording to my server.

```
 read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
```

Now my question is if someone wanted to be malicious they could directly post to my server script using up internal memory, bandwidth, and possibly buffer overflow. Is there a way to prevent how much information comes from the user?

I tried this before the read line, but I am not entirely sure this is the correct way to do it. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
if ($ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'} > 100000) {
 #then return some error message / exit
}
```

EDIT AND SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM:

```
 use CGI qw/:standard/;
 use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
 $CGI::POST_MAX=1024 * 100;  # max 100K posts
 #$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS = 1;  # no uploads

 $uploaded_file = param( 'POSTDATA' );
 if (!$uploaded_file && cgi_error()) {
  print header(-status=>cgi_error());
  exit 0;
 }
```

I want to thank all of you for your quick responses (upvotes for all) but i have to give the correct answer to the first person who posted the correct link, despite their lack of effort in writing anything. I guess thats only fair? What do you guys think, leave comment below.

Comment: Actually, I don't think so. If I went to someone for technical advice and she said, "Go read this man page", and the next person over instead said, "You can use this; it's documented on that man page", I'd personally find the second answer to be the better answer. If it was going to take a medium-size essay to answer the question, then by all means suggest a page, but in this case, the actual answer was very simple and could (should) have been inlined.

Comment: I guess that makes sense Joe, I am fairly newish to Stackoverflow and don't know the proper etiquette when it comes to assigning correct answer, especially when all 3 linked to the same link. I'll switch the correct answer then.

Comment: This also makes the most useful answer appear first on the page, which is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say it is a Perl script but don't mention the Perl [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI.pm) module.  If you use that module (which I recommend), there is some limited support for denial-of-service protection.  For example, you can set:

```
$CGI::POST_MAX = 100000;
```

and CGI.pm will exit your script with an error if any posts that are too large show up.

There's a [decent discussion](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI.pm#Avoiding_Denial_of_Service_Attacks) of how to avoid denial-of-service attacks in the man page.

Comment: I've decided to give you the correct answer because you brought to my attention that i am not using the CGI.pm module (i was doing it in an old school way) and also posted the relevant code snippet and link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to prevent how much information comes from the user?

Stated that simply, no.  Because once it gets to something in your control (the server), it's already come from the user.  See [denial of service attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).

It's mostly a matter of where you filter out the noise.  For example:

- If the application can quickly [filter out bad requests](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#Avoiding-Denial-of-Service-Attacks), they won't take up unnecessary processing resources.
- If the web server can filter out requests which are too large, the application won't be bothered with them.
- If the router can filter out requests which are too large, the server won't be bothered with them.
- If the ISP can filter out requests from known malicious sources, your infrastructure won't be bothered with them.

A really malicious user can deliver a bad enough attack that your server isn't even an issue anymore.  The rack at your ISP can be hosed.

Answer (score 1):

[*Avoiding Denial of Service Attacks* in `CGI`](http://p3rl.org/CGI#Avoiding-Denial-of-Service-Attacks)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: See my comment above; I think directly mentioning $CGI::POST_MAX would have been more helpful. Otherwise it comes off as an RTFM.